# build.gradle - how to copy only the resources from a dependency jar?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a dependency jar called A, which contains a resource directory. Inside that, there are four directors a,b,c,d. I would like to unpack this jar and copy only the contents of the resource directory to my project directory. How can I achieve this?

I have tried:

```
configurations {
    ajar
}

dependencies {
    ajar 'group:ajar:version'
}

task unpackResources(type: Copy) {
    from {configurations.ajar.collect { zipTree(it) }}
    into "${rootProject.projectDir}/dir/"
}

build.dependsOn(unpackResources)
```

This will copy all contents of ajar. How do I further filter it to only the resources(dirs a,b,c,d)?